# Redirect loop in codeigniter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a site on my https://mydomainname.com.

While working today i had to change permission of a file to make or writable (although i dont think any problem was caused due to this ) and since then the site has gone into a redirect Loop. Site is built Up in php using codeigniter Framework.

My directory structure is :

```
/var/www/html/myprojectRoot
```

My server's default DocumentRoot is `/var/www/html/`

inside html i have .htaccess file as follows :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /myprojectRoot/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|javascript|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /myprojectRoot/index.php/$1 [L]
```

My baseurl is set to https://mydomainname.com

I can see in firebug console that the sute is being redirected between 
https://mydomainname.com  and https://mydomainname.com/myprojectRoot

Can someone explain the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your `/myprojectRoot/.htaccess` like this:

```
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteBase /myprojectRoot/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

then inside `/myprojectRoot/application/config/config.php` you need to have these config settings:

```
$config['base_url']     = '';
$config['index_page']   = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

---

Your root .htaccess should be like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((?!myprojectRoot/).*)$ /myprojectRoot/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: It would really help you if you spend some more time in typing and provide relevant details. That comment doesn't tell me anything. What URL did you enter in browser? Where is your .htaccess located? Did you test from a different browser?

Comment: I entered the url `https://mydomainname.com` and i am still geting a redirect loop error. My .htaccess is located in `/var/www/html/.htaccess`  which is as shown above. And i just added a new .htaccess in `/var/www/html/myprojectRoot/.htaccess` as you said.  Still getting the redirect loop error

Comment: I provided your updated root .htaccess as well. Replace your's with this one. Do test for a new browser or clear browser cache.

Answer (score -1):

i think it is not the issue you might change the code.
You should check the code where you are performing your redirect function.
And there it redirects there might be a check to go in else it will take back from where its redirected.

```
And it become a redirect loop. From one method to another.
```